# How to reorder an array to have a key in ascending order, based on an array of values?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to run a database migration, and I've run into a chronological issue. I can't change the behaviour, so I have to deal with it somehow.

Suppose I have the following array,

```
const arr = [
  { model: 'modelE', associations: ['modelA'], order: 1 },
  { model: 'modelA', associations: [ 'modelB' ], order: 2 },
  { model: 'modelB', associations: [], order: 3 },
  { model: 'modelC', associations: ['modelA', 'modelB'], order: 4 },
  { model: 'modelD', associations: ['modelA'], order: 5 },
  { model: 'modelF', associations: [], order: 6 },
]
```

As we know, we have to create these tables in order, otherwise the foreign keys cannot be created and, therefore, an error will be thrown.

In this case, we have `modelE`, `modelC` and `modelD` that depend on `modelA`, but `modelA` depends on `modelB`, so `modelB` must be the first element in this array, because it has to be the first table to be created.

The resulting array should look like this:

```
const arr = [
  { model: 'modelB', associations: [], order: 1 },
  { model: 'modelF', associations: [], order: 2 },
  { model: 'modelA', associations: [ 'modelB' ], order: 3 },
  { model: 'modelC', associations: ['modelA', 'modelB'], order: 4 },
  { model: 'modelE', associations: ['modelC'], order: 5 },
  { model: 'modelD', associations: ['modelA'], order: 6 },
]
```

Is there an effective way of doing this? All I can think of is running a `sort` function with `arr.find`s inside it. Not sure if this is too performant or even readable.

Comment: Can there be cyclical dependencies? This feels more like a directed graph/tree than an array sorting problem to me. Use the graph/tree once built to make an array in an order that works.

Comment: The solution can be whatever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a [topological ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting).

You can use a depth-first algorithm for that:

```js
function topoSort(arr) {
    const visited = new Set;
    const map = new Map(arr.map(({model, associations}) => [model, associations]));
    
    function dfs(models) {
        for (let model of models) {
            if (visited.has(model)) continue;
            dfs(map.get(model));
            visited.add(model);
        }
    }
    
    dfs([...map.keys()]);
    return Array.from(visited, (model, i) => 
        ({model, associations: map.get(model), order: i+1})
    );
}

const arr = [
  { model: 'modelE', associations: ['modelA'], order: 1 },
  { model: 'modelA', associations: [ 'modelB' ], order: 2 },
  { model: 'modelB', associations: [], order: 3 },
  { model: 'modelC', associations: ['modelA', 'modelB'], order: 4 },
  { model: 'modelD', associations: ['modelA'], order: 5 },
  { model: 'modelF', associations: [], order: 6 },
]
const result = topoSort(arr);
console.log(...result);
```

Comment: I get a different result with this than what the OP wanted {
  associations: [],
  model: "modelB",
  order: 1
}, {
  associations: ["modelB"],
  model: "modelA",
  order: 2
}, {
  associations: ["modelA"],
  model: "modelE",
  order: 3
}, {
  associations: ["modelA", "modelB"],
  model: "modelC",
  order: 4
}, {
  associations: ["modelA"],
  model: "modelD",
  order: 5
}, {
  associations: [],
  model: "modelF",
  order: 6
}

Comment: I've noticed that as well, but it's fine if modelF is last. It doesn't have dependencies and nothing depends on it, so it can be created at any time.

Comment: A topological ordering is not necessarily unique. There are several valid topological orderings for the example at hand.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const sortArrayByDependency = (arr) => {
  const sorted = [];
  const foundSet = new Set();
  const maxLoop = arr.length;
  let loopCount = 0;
  
  while(arr.length > 0 && loopCount < maxLoop) {
    loopCount += 1;
    const first = arr.shift();
    if(first.associations.every(ele => foundSet.has(ele))){
      sorted.push({...first, order: sorted.length + 1 });
      foundSet.add(first.model)
    }
    else {
      arr.push(first)
    }
  }
  
  return sorted;
}

const arr = [
  { model: 'modelB', associations: [], order: 1 },
  { model: 'modelF', associations: [], order: 2 },
  { model: 'modelA', associations: [ 'modelB' ], order: 3 },
  { model: 'modelC', associations: ['modelA', 'modelB'], order: 4 },
  { model: 'modelE', associations: ['modelC'], order: 5 },
  { model: 'modelD', associations: ['modelA'], order: 6 },
]

console.log(sortArrayByDependency(arr))
```